# Difference between `/sbin/service postgresql-9.1 start` and `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.1 start`

Tags: centos, postgresql

I have seen two ways to start a postgresql server:

`/sbin/service postgresql-9.1 start`

`/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.1 start`

Could anyone explain the difference between these two? Or there's no difference at all?

The OS we are using is CentOS 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your system, and most "older" systems, `service` does the same thing as running the init script.  Depending on the implementation, it might set a more predictable environment, so it's still preferred to use it if available.

The general idea, however, is that `service` will also work with newer init systems.  So for example, if you have Upstart, then `service` will instead of running some script signal the Upstart system to start or stop a service.  So to be future-proof, use `service`.

Answer (score 1):

None.

As per `man`:

> service - run a System V init script

Answer (score 1):

None.
/sbin/service is just generic script that will run init script and pass the command (you will see if you take a look at /sbin/service)
So basicly now you can say: `service name command[start/stop/status/restart/...]`